# How to get a method list from a category

Tags: ios

As we know, get a method list from a class can use the code below.

```
    int unsigned numMethods;
Method *methods = class_copyMethodList(objc_getClass("NSArray"), &numMethods);
for (int i = 0 ; i < numMethods; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(method_getName(methods[i])));
}
```

But if these is a category for the specified class, like UIColor+FlatUI.
And I add some class methods in this category.

**My question is how to get the those methods defined in this category?**